# Can a statement with all AND statements have a Disjunctive Normal Form?

Tags: boolean-algebra

If I have something like:

```
p AND q AND r AND s
```

Is there a way to rewrite this in Disjunctive Normal Form?

Comment: This is already in disjunctive normal form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A statement is in DNF when it is a disjunction of 1 or more disjuncts, where each disjunct is a conjunction of 1 or more literals, where each literal is an atomic statement or the negation of an atomic statement.

Your statement can be seen exactly as such: it is a disjunction of one disjunct, which is a conjunction of literals.  So, it is in DNF.